# Strtok returns NULL for last token of string

Tags: c, string, null, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm writing an assembler program in C that takes assembly code (of a made up architecture) and manipulates it to create an executable program.

The line I'm trying to parse is:

```
jmp L1
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
int line_count = 0;
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char original_line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char *first_field;
char label[MAX_LABEL_LENGTH];
char *argument;
int arguments_in_line = 0;
while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
    line_count++;
    strcpy(original_line, line);
    first_field = strtok(line, delimit);
    if(is_valid_label(first_field)) { /* first field is label */
        strcpy(label,first_field);
        first_field = strtok(NULL, delimit); 
    }
    if(!is_entry_or_external(first_field)) {
        arguments_in_line = get_num_operands(original_line);
        if(arguments_in_line == UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
            return UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
        else if(arguments_in_line == 0) {
            continue; 
        }
        else if(arguments_in_line == 1) { 
            argument = strtok(NULL, delimit);
            if(is_valid_label_name(argument)) /* SEGFAULT HERE!!! */
                printf("found needed replacement at line %d, replace label: %s", line_count, argument);
        }
    }
}
```

So at the second or third (depends on the input, for the example line it is the second) call of strtok, argument gets NULL and a segfault occours. 
The values before calling strtok is:

```
(gdb) p line
$1 = "jmp L1\000\000\000\000\000\000[q\346\267\000\360... /* more values */
```

After the first call:

```
(gdb) p line
$2 = "jmp\000L1\000\000\000\000\000\000[q\346\267\000\360... /* more values */
```

And the second one returns NULL.

The method `get_num_operands` looks like:

```
int get_num_operands(char *src_line) {
    char line_copy[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char *first_field;
    strcpy(line_copy, src_line);
    first_field = strtok(line_copy, delimit);
    if(is_valid_label(first_field)) /* first field is label */
        first_field = strtok(NULL, delimit); /* make sure first field is a command or instruciton */
    if (first_field == NULL)
        return UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
    else 
        return get_num_arguments_for_command(first_field);
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It should be *trivial* to manufacture a [mcve] exhibiting your problem. A four line `main` should do it, as we will then see *exactly* how you're calling `strtok` in effort to acquire the *second* field. Please make an mcve and update your question.

Comment: You don't show how you make the *second* call to `strtok`. Was it with a `NULL` as in `second_field = strtok(NULL, delimit);`? Note too that since you read the string with `fgets` that `delimit` should be `" \n"`.

Comment: Adding the source code to your question would help.

Comment: @WeatherVane I had the same initial thought. But if he simply forgot to replace `line` with `NULL` in the second call, it should have returned `"jmp"` again, instead of returning `NULL`. Unless he did something to mess with `line` prior to the second `strtok` call.

Comment: Also clarifying, non of the other methods are using `line`. I used `original_line` for some which copied the values of line. also `line` has some other values at the end other then `\000`.

Comment: Is the code missing some `{` braces `}` after `if(!is_entry_or_external(first_field))`? The indentation suggests that it is. Also the incomplete code begs the question: to which `if` does the final `else` belong?

Comment: please read: [mcve]

Comment: Here is an MCVE: https://onlinegdb.com/H1swJJI84
It prints both tokens with no problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited again. It occoured with the braces.

Comment: So that was the fault? Without them the lines after `arguments_in_line = get_num_operands(original_line);` would execute anyway. There have been comments about the use of `{}` braces recently - always use them even if it's only one line of code that doesn't "need" them. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was not the fault. I found my solution. Will post it here when and if this gets unlocked. I was actually using strtok again in another method: `get_num_operands`. So the failed `strtok` usage was trying to get a token for a tapped out string. I'm also adding the missing code to my question now.

Comment: `strtok` is not re-entrant. Now do you understand the need for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem? It's a (minimal) complete program that users can compile and run.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am aware of that about `strtok`. And yes, I do understand that need better now. Again thank you all for your patiance.

Comment: There are other benefits too: the very act of boiling the code down to an MCVE can allow you to find the problem on the way- that "ah" moment.